# Execute Stored procedure without using java based tasklet

Tags: java, spring-batch

I am able to execute stored procedure by implementing tasklet.

But is it possible to execute stored procedure from configuration job.xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `StoredProcedureItemReader` works like the `JdbcCursorItemReader`, except that, instead of running a query to obtain a cursor, it runs a stored procedure that returns a cursor. The stored procedure can return the cursor in three different ways:

1. As a returned ResultSet (used by SQL Server, Sybase, DB2, Derby, and
   MySQL).
2. As a ref-cursor returned as an out parameter (used by Oracle and
       PostgreSQL).
3. As the return value of a stored function call

Sample Java configuration

```
@Bean
public StoredProcedureItemReader reader(DataSource dataSource) {
        StoredProcedureItemReader reader = new StoredProcedureItemReader();

        reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
        reader.setProcedureName("sp_customer_credit");
        reader.setRowMapper(new CustomerCreditRowMapper());    
        return reader;
}
```

In case you want to return curser

```
@Bean
public StoredProcedureItemReader reader(DataSource dataSource) {
        StoredProcedureItemReader reader = new StoredProcedureItemReader();

        reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
        reader.setProcedureName("sp_customer_credit");
        reader.setRowMapper(new CustomerCreditRowMapper());
        reader.setRefCursorPosition(1);

        return reader;
}
```

Comment: yes you are correct but my requirement is different.

Comment: I dont want to  use itemReader which returns, instead just to execute my store procedure.

Comment: Then taskle is the option. Why you want to implement it in job.xml?